# Transition delay doesn't work with border

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

```css
.hovereffect:hover > .hidden {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 2em;
  border: thin solid white;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.hovereffect .hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  clear: both;
  height: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
  border: none;
  transition-property: opacity height padding border;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  width: 15em;
  margin: 0.1em 0em 0.1em 1em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FBF0D4;
  color: #725D29;
  border: thin solid white;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
  background-color: #725D29;
  color: #FBF0D4;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/guitar">Menu 1</a>
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <a href="/software">Menu 2</a>
    <a class="hidden" href="/software/practicaluml">Submenu 1</a>
    <a class="hidden" href="/software/trusting_trust">Submenu 2</a>
  </div>
  <a href="/sketches">Menu 3</a>
  <a href="/sketches">Menu 4</a>
</nav>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ke9cc0c7/

I am trying to show a list of sub menus on :hover over a menu item, which is hidden otherwise. But the collapsing list was causing menu items to change position the moment user moved mouse away from the submenu, forcing an unsuspecting user to chase after a preferred link. So I decided to add a transition-delay. But for some reason it doesn't work on border! (See the JSFiddle link for demo.) The moment user moves mouse away from the submenu, border is reset to 0 without any delay.

Any particular mistake I am making? I am just a learner.

Comment: You can't transition from border to no-border. `border: 0` may work

Comment: @SexyTurnip Thanks. This was quite obvious, considering I was just reading about it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the `border-style` property is not a [transitionable property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/). When you transition from `border:none` to `border: thin solid white`, the `border-style` is also being changed along with the `border-color` and the `border-width`. The [initial value of `border-style` is `none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-style).

Setting `border: 0px solid white` as the initial value would make it work properly because `border-style` remains the same even though border itself is removed because the width is 0px and would not produce any visual difference.

```css
.hovereffect:hover > .hidden {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 2em;
  border: thin solid white;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.hovereffect .hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  clear: both;
  height: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
  border: 0px solid white;
  transition-property: opacity height padding border;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  width: 15em;
  margin: 0.1em 0em 0.1em 1em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FBF0D4;
  color: #725D29;
  border: thin solid white;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
  background-color: #725D29;
  color: #FBF0D4;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/guitar">Menu 1</a>
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <a href="/software">Menu 2</a>
    <a class="hidden" href="/software/practicaluml">Submenu 1</a>
    <a class="hidden" href="/software/trusting_trust">Submenu 2</a>
  </div>
  <a href="/sketches">Menu 3</a>
  <a href="/sketches">Menu 4</a>
</nav>
```

You can find the full list of animatable/transitionable properties in the [spec here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/).